# Convert Word document into PDF using excel VBA code

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I wrote below code to take screenshot form Excel document and paste on word document.It works fine However I am unable to convert This Word document into PDF and error displays"Object does not support this property or method".It seems that i defined Variable (Objword as variant) not correct.Please any one can help.

```
Sub CopyToWordPicture()

Dim WDApp As Word.Application
Dim WDDoc As Word.Document

Dim objword As variant


Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objword.Visible = True
objword.Documents.Open "C:\Automation\BH Report\Daily&BH RAN KPI report_ok.docx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Automation\BH Report\Daily_Hourly KPI Template.xlsx"
Sheets("BH_Graphs").Select
Range("A1:k50").CopyPicture xlPrinter
    With objword
        '.Documents.Add
        .Selection.Paste
        .Visible = True

    End With

    'WDApp.Visible = True
   ' WDApp.Selection.GoToNext wdGoToPage

    Windows("Daily_Hourly KPI Template.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Daily_Graphs").Select
    Range("A1:J50").CopyPicture xlPrinter

    With objword
        '.Documents.Add
        .Selection.Paste
        .Visible = True
    End With


    'export as PDF

  objword.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="C:\Automation\BH Report\Daily&BH RAN KPI report.pdf", _
     ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF


    end sub
```

Comment: This line `Workbooks.Open Filename:=` works as is?

Comment: yes. It work fine to open my excel document

Comment: Wow ok. Good to know.

Comment: @findwindow just out of curiosity, why did you think it wouldn't work?

Comment: @MacroMan always thought you needed a `set`.

Comment: @findwindow you only need `set` if you want to assign the workbook to a variable as an object. If you just want to open a workbook without assigning it to anything you can call the `Workbooks.Open` method on its own. In fact, you can use any of its properties or methods without the `Set` keyword.

Comment: I have change the code below and Now its working fine and also converting word document into PDF.But now one extra word document is also created.Any idea to delete this extra word page.
        Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.application")
Set wddoc = appWD.Documents.Open("C:\y.docx")
    appWD.Visible = True
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\.xlsx"
Sheets("Bh").Select
    Sheets("BH_Graphs").Range("A1:L44").CopyPicture xlScreen
    appWD.Selection.Paste
    Sheets("Daily").Range("A1:L44").CopyPicture xlScreen 
    appWD.Selection.Paste
    wddoc.ExportAsFixedFormat "C:\x.pdf", wdExportFormatPDF